# WSO2 Identity Manager 5.6 : backup and restore procedures

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Good morning,

I looked in the forum here and could not find the answer. If I overlooked it, I apologize...

I just joined an existing project team using `WSO2` Identity Manager 5.6 and API Gateway.
I understand that `WSO2` Identity Manager is made up of several components, among which openLDAP (which contains a Berkeley database) and a `postgreSQL` database.
The current backup / restore procedures simply 'tar' the whole directory which contains all files related to `WSO2` (including directories which contain database files), without stopping `WSO2`.
I'm a bit doubtful about this type of process for backing up. Is that the right thing to do?
If not, what would the right procedure be?

If I understand correctly, `postgreSQL` is only used for `WSO2` 'internal state data' storage, so backing it up may not be useful. So I'm thinking that maybe an export of openLDAP (slapcat command) be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Backing openLDAP is probably not enough. Depending on how the WSO2 components (IS + APIM) are installed, you may also have H2 DBs for the local registry, Solr indexes for the UI, Velocity templates for API deployments, and/or Synapse XMLs for the APIs.

I recommend you to first compare your installation directories and files with the vanilla zips so you know how is it configured before changing your backup process.

Comment: H2 DB? I did not see any, I saw a postgreSQL. Do they serve the same aim?

Comment: similar aim. Check the master-datasources.xml and metrics-datasources.xml on {wso2}/repository/conf/datasources to find out what dbs are configured in your system